# MYSQL - Query many to many relation on multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have two tables (player and group) with a many to many relation and a junction table (player_group):

Table "player"

[image: Table "player"]
Table "group"

[image: Table "group"]
and the junction table:

Table "player_group"

[image: Table "player_group"]

A player can be part of many groups and a group can have many players. A user can also be a group's admin represented by the flag "flg_admin".

I want to build a query that tells me, for a specific player (lets say player1 with id=27):

- The name of the groups that a player belongs to;
- The amount of players in each of the groups that a player belongs to;
- If a player is the admin of each group.

So for player1 (ID=27) the result would be:

```
|group_name|no. members|flg_admin|
----------------------------------
|GROUP A   |         2 |        1|
|GROUP B   |         3 |        0|
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT(x.id_player) as num_players, x.flg_admin 
FROM player_group x 
JOIN group g ON x.id_group=g.id 
WHERE id_group IN ( 
    SELECT
    id_group 
    FROM player_group 
    WHERE id_player=27) 
GROUP BY id_group;
```

However with this query i get the following result:

```
|group_name|no. members|flg_admin|
----------------------------------
|GROUP A   |         2 |        1|
|GROUP B   |         3 |        1|
```

The flg_admin is set as 1 for GROUP B but as you can see in the images above, this player is not an admin of GROUP B.
I have been trying to get this right for hours to no avail and i have exhausted my options, any help with this query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.flg_admin` is not taken from the row of the table for the selected player, it's coming from an arbitrary row in the group.

You need to join with the `player_group` table twice so you can get this column from the correct row.

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT(*) as num_players, y.flg_admin 
FROM player_group x 
JOIN `group` g ON x.id_group=g.id 
JOIN player_group y ON y.id_group = x.id_group
WHERE y.id_player = 27
GROUP BY x.id_group
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17331f/1)

BTW, you shouldn't use `group` as a table or column name, because it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I figured that would be the problem but couldn't wrap my head around how to solve it. I'm not using `group` as the table name because my column names are not in english, i just translated everything for the sake of convenience. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT g.name AS group_name
    , (SELECT count(*) FROM player_group AS px WHERE px.id_group = pg.id_group) AS "no. members"
    , flg_admin
FROM players AS p
JOIN player_group AS pg on p.id = pg.id_player
JOIN "group" AS g on pg.id_group = g.id
WHERE p.username = 'player1';
```

maybe.

Answer (score 0):

My alternative solution using subquery:

```
select tgrp.name, mgrp.members, pgrp.flg_admin
from player_group pgrp
  join `group` tgrp on pgrp.id_group=tgrp.id
  join (
    select id_group, count(*) members
    from player_group
    group by id_group
  ) mgrp on tgrp.id=mgrp.id_group
where pgrp.id_player=27;
```